# Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 404 - ajax request browser

Tags: javascript, ajax, cors, httprequest, http-status-code-404

I have a 404 error with my ajax req (which looks like this) :

```js
$.ajax({
    type:'GET',
    url:'http://localhost:8000/auth/github',
    crossDomain:true,
    headers:{
        'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*'
    },
    success:function(data){debugger;}
});
```

The error looks like this on chrome :
[see chrome error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lceRY.png)

And like this one in firefox :
[see firefox error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ravu4.png)

I installed cors plugin in my browser, I've tried many changes on the headers, still got the error in my web console.

Also, when I acces my route with postman it all works fine.
So I assume the problem come from my browser

Does someone knows how to fix it ?

I saw this topic with the same error but it has no answer yet : [Ajax: Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47252264/ajax-response-for-preflight-has-invalid-http-status-code-404/50251359#50251359)

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured it out by adding in my headers accept:*/*.
I know this is forbidden in real infra, but mine was just for school so for those who meet the same problem for a school project, just see the trick.